# Format code does do work with vscode 1.1.1 and typescript 1.8.10

Tags: autocomplete, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode 1.1.1 with typescript.

Since i moved to typescript 1.8.10, i'm not able to have the 'format code' command to work anymore, neither the auto completion, neither the on the fly error checking and problem matcher.

Is vscode bound to a specific typescript version ?

Thanks

Comment: Shamless plug for the TypeScript IDE I created for myself to help reduce the effort to get stuff to work http://alm.tools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is shipped with support for the most recent stable release of TypeScript, which means *the version of Visual Studio Code that you're using (the April 2016 release), supports TypeScript 1.8.9*.

**Visual Studio Code 1.2.0, which should be released within the next couple days, comes bundled with support for TypeScript 1.8.10** (see [this commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/c41449712110d5185fe05dca59488e10e1ba7a9c)).

Since Visual Studio Code 1.2.0 (the May 2016 release), is still a couple days away, you have the option of [manually switching Visual Studio Code to a newer version of TypeScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions).

Comment: Thanks you ! 
npm install -g typescript@1.8.9 did the trick !